# jQuery UI Datepicker for future reservation

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

As it is obvious that hotel reservation is only possible to start from current date to at least next day. I am using jQuery UI Date picker and I want to add functionality like this link shows,

[www.phpjabbers.com/hotels-booking-system/demo.php](http://www.phpjabbers.com/hotels-booking-system/demo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following piece of code:

```
var objDate = new Date();
var sToday =(objDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + objDate.getDate() + '/' + objDate.getFullYear();
var sTomorrow =(objDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + (objDate.getDate()+1) + '/' + objDate.getFullYear();

$("#dtPickerFrom").val(sToday);
$("#dtPickerTo").val(sTomorrow);
```

Let me know, if this works for you.

Comment: @nrage .. if you think my answer has solved your issue, please mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this one.

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(date){
        //alert("none");
        var date1 = jQuery('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');           
        var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) ); 
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );        
        var newDate = date.toDateString(); 
        newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );                      
        jQuery('#datepicker2').datepicker("option","minDate",newDate);            
    } 
    });
    jQuery( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
        minDate: '+1d',
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
       });
 });
</script>
```